# Page Reload Delay after submit JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been trying to delay page reload after submit, using the script below but i can't make it to work. I'm wondering if someone can help me. Thanks.

Button

```
<input type="submit" id="success" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" value ="Save"  onclick="refresh(10000)" value="Call function"/>
```

Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh (timeoutPeriod){ 
    refresh = setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery it should be something like that:

```
$('#yourformid').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},timeoutPeriod);
});
```

it means, you should catch form submit event, then prevent default action, and reload the page after timeout expires.

EDIT:

in case you need to submit the form with a delay, not just reload it:

```
var readyToSubmit = false;
$('#yourformid').submit(function(e){
  var $self = $(this);
  if (!readyToSubmit) {
    setTimeout(function(){
       readyToSubmit = true;
       $self.submit();
    },2000);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtn2wLnv/

Comment: The also prevent form's data to be sent to the server.

Comment: the question contains reload ... nothing mentioned about submit, but it is required, not a big deel to change a bit the code and submit the data.

Comment: It's in the title: Page Reload Delay after **submit** JSP

Comment: see my edit, as i told it is easy, no need of AJAX, but if you prefer AJAX it is alway an option.

Comment: you can add a `+` to the answer or/and mark it with a tick if you think that's the best answer of the question